# UdpClient send and receive async on same port

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, udpclient

I am trying to send data using UdpClient to a piece of hardware that then sends a "response" on the same port.

Obviously I first ran into the problem that everyone else trying to do the same thing had and realised I had to do it using 2 UdpClients.

I have seen a few examples but nothing that would quite fit my needs.

I came up with the following solution that seems to do the trick, but I am looking for some sort of validation from gurus out there.

```cs
public async Task< byte[] > ReceiveAsync( byte[] datagram, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
{
    byte[] buffer = null;

    var tasks = new List< Task >
    {
        Task.Run( async () =>
        {
            using ( var client = new UdpClient( 5555 ) )
            {
                client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 200;
                var receiveDatagram = await client.ReceiveAsync();
                buffer = receiveDatagram.Buffer;
            }
        }, cancellationToken ),
        Task.Run( async () =>
        {
            using ( var client = new UdpClient() )
            {
                client.Connect( "10.0.0.50", 5555 );
                await client.SendAsync( datagram, datagram.Length );
            }
        }, cancellationToken )
    };

    await Task.WhenAll( tasks.ToArray() );
    return buffer;
}
```

Does this seem to be correct or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Simultaneous send and receive on a single UDP socket is definitely allowed.  2. For UDP, you don't want to be anywhere near that `Connect` method.  UDP is connectionless, and the kinda-sorta connection simulation that `Connect` does with a UDP socket is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Do you mean going with 2 clients isn't the right way? I have tried with 1 client only having the receive right after the send, but did not get any data back.

Comment: When I'm using UDP, I generally keep one socket open for the life of the application, and turn incoming datagrams into events.  But there's no reason that your two tasks + WhenAll method can't work.  Just make the using block cover the entire lifespan of both tasks.

Comment: I have just tried again with only 1 client, and I realised why it didn't work before, I'll post the answer, thanks for your input @BenVoigt

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ben Voigt's input on the Connect method (do not use) I realised I should have used the port number in the UdpClient constructor too (which seemed redundant at first since I was connecting to it).

The new solution is alot easier, cleaner, and works :)

```csharp
public static async Task< byte[] > ReceiveAsync( byte[] datagram )
{
    using ( var client = new UdpClient( 5555 ) )
    {
        client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 200;
        await client.SendAsync( datagram, datagram.Length, "10.0.0.50", 5555 );
        var buffer = await client.ReceiveAsync();
        return buffer.Buffer;
    }
}
```

Thanks!